# Forming JPQL query from native SQL query for multiple views with CASE condition and join statements

Tags: jpa, jpql

Kindly helping in converting native query ti JPQL query for multiple views with CASE condition and join statements.Table c1 and c3 are views. I am trying the get the current and pending information from c1. 
Please find the query mentioned below

```
    SELECT c3.eqip_id  AS EQIP_ID, 
           CASE  WHEN c1.inst_ts IS NULL OR c1.sent_ts > c1.inst_ts THEN c1.ver_nm  END  AS PEND, 
           CASE  WHEN c1.sent_ts IS NULL OR c1.sent_ts > c1.inst_ts THEN c1.ver_nm  END  AS CURRENT, 
           c1.trm_ver_hist_id AS TRM_VER_HIST_ID 
    FROM   trm_ver_hist_vw c1 
           JOIN(SELECT Max(trm_ver_hist_id) AS TRM_VER_HIST_ID, dvc_id, status 
                FROM   trm_ver_hist_vw 
                WHERE  ver_typ_id = 1  AND status IN( 'C', 'P' ) 
                GROUP  BY dvc_id, status) c2 
             ON c1.trm_ver_hist_id = c2.trm_ver_hist_id 
           JOIN trm_dtl_vw c3  ON c1.dvc_id = c3.trm_id 
    WHERE  c3.co_actv_ind = 'Y'  AND c3.mach_hdwr_asscn_ind = 'Y' AND pin = 'ABC'
```

Can anyone please help me to make this query in JPA/JPQL?

Answer (score 0):

It seems very complex and data specific.  I would recommend using a native SQL query.

The JPA spec does not allow selects in the FROM clause, although EclipseLink does have some support for this.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Sub-selects_in_FROM_clause